# Dialog center title android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have to center the title text in Dialog `custom.setTitle("Center Text");`?

Wherer `Dialog custom;`

Thanks!

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you're asking. Would you please clarify your question?

Comment: Is possible get the title text centered in the AlertDialog window?

Answer (score 0):

*Try this one *

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

TextView titleView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
if(titleView != null){
    titleView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
```

[For more information, check this article](http://kodecenter.com/article?id=2390ec63-63d7-4534-a76f-cc3b10497a2c)